# how to write xslt query using two tables

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<Company_Y>
    <Branch>
        <branchNo>11</branchNo><street>163 Main street</street><city>abc</city><postcode>111</postcode>
    </Branch>
    <Staff>
        <staffNo>11</staffNo><Name>abhishek</Name><position>asd</position><sex>m</sex><DOB>01-Feb-1991</DOB><salary>122</salary><branchNo>11</branchNo>
    </Staff>
    <PropertyforRent>
        <propertyNo>11</propertyNo><street>163 Main street</street><city>abc</city><postcode>111</postcode><type>a</type><rooms>3</rooms><rent>334</rent><ownerNo>23</ownerNo><staffNo>11</staffNo><branchNo>11</branchNo>
    </PropertyforRent>
    <Client>
        <clientNo>22</clientNo><Name>dsf</Name><telNo>33</telNo><prefType>gdf</prefType><maxRent>343</maxRent>
    </Client>
    <PrivateOwner>
        <ownerNo>23</ownerNo><Name>dsfd</Name><address>dfsd</address><telNo>3423</telNo>
    </PrivateOwner> 
    <Viewing>
        <clientNo>23</clientNo><propertyNo>dfg</propertyNo><viewDate>01-Feb-1991</viewDate><comment>dgfsdsd</comment>
    </Viewing>
    <Registration>
        <clientNo>34</clientNo><branchNo>11</branchNo><staffNo>11</staffNo><dateJoined>01-Feb-1991</dateJoined>
    </Registration> 
</Company_Y>
```

***This is what i used for creating xml file***

Branch (branchNo, street, city, postcode)

Staff (staffNo, Name, position, sex, DOB, salary, branchNo)

PropertyforRent (propertyNo, street, city, postcode, type, rooms, rent, ownerNo, staffNo,
branchNo)

Client (clientNo, Name, telNo, prefType, maxRent)

PrivateOwner (ownerNo, Name, address, telNo)

Viewing (clientNo, propertyNo, viewDate, comment)

Registration (clientNo, branchNo, staffNo, dateJoined)

**I have to write xslt for this

List the name of staff who work in the branch whose street address is ‘163 Main street’.**

what i have written is this and it is not working . PLZ help??

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>List the name of staff who work in the branch whose street address is ‘163 Main street’</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>name</th>
        <th>street</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="Company_Y/Branch">
      <xsl:if test="street='163 Main street'">
         p=value-of select="branchNo"
           <xsl:for-each select="Company_Y/Staff">
              <xsl:if test1="branchNo=p">
              <tr>
                   <td><xsl:value-of select="branchNo"/></td>
                   <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
              </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Opening and closing tags do not match so, your xsl is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the target branchNo to an xsl variable and use that in the for-each loop

```
<xsl:variable name="branch" select="Company_Y/Branch[street='163 Main street']/branchNo" />
<xsl:for-each select="Company_Y/Staff[branchNo=$branch]">
  <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="branchNo"/></td>
    <th><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></th>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```